# JavaScript hierarchy, why is parent variables undefined?

Tags: javascript, class, parent-child, hierarchy

I wrote two classes the other day, where I needed to override and call the overridden method (getQuery).

```
//parent
function SimpleUser() {
   this.firstName = "X";
}

SimpleUser.prototype.getQuery = function(sub) {
  //solution for not getting undefined variables
  var that = sub || this; 
  var query = "first="+that.firstName;
  return query;
}

//child
function User() {
  //extends 
  this.base = SimpleUser;
  //super()
  this.base();

  //prints "X"
  console.log(this.firstName);

  this.lastName = "Y";
}

//override
User.prototype.getQuery = function() {
  //call parent
  var query = SimpleUser.prototype.getQuery.call(this);
  query += "&last="+this.lastName;
  return query;
}

//prints "first=X"
console.log(new SimpleUser().getQuery());

//prints "first=undefined&last=Y" if I don't use parameter "sub"
console.log(new User().getQuery());
```

When I call the method "getQuery" from the sub-class, all variables in the parent are undefined. If I call them from the constructor of the sub-class, they're fine.

I solved the problem by passing the sub-class as parameter and just checking who's asking.

Can someone please explain to me why this happens and help me to find a better solution than what I had to do with passing the sub-class itself as a parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems to work, also without `sub`: http://jsfiddle.net/qqeV3/.

Comment: Why haven't you used `var User = new SimpleUser();`

Comment: Strange. I don't see why it should not work (though you do inheritance using uncommon idioms, super constructor call would normally be `SimpleUser.call(this)` without `base` and you also miss `User.prototype = Object.create(SimpleUser.prototype)`, since it is normal to chain prototypes; but none of it should be the problem for your functionality).

Comment: [Your code works just fine without passing "sub".](http://jsfiddle.net/E7gcJ/)

Comment: When I copy/paste your code, I get `first=X&last=Y` as the result of the last `console.log`. So what's the problem?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? -- http://jsfiddle.net/XC4Ys/1/

Comment: @Jackson: There's no substantive change in the outcome of your code.

Comment: I copied it again and it worked. Don't know what I did wrong before, but no matter what it always turned out undefined. Must have made some changes after I added the sub parameter, didn't have the original code when I wrote the question. My apologies. Thanks for the comments and answers!

Comment: @herby I haven't been working much with Javascript hierarchy and by using base I was able to make both a parent and a grandparent. Still trying to learn the best way with object in JavaScript.

Comment: @Emil: Ok. Established way too call a parent constructor is via `call`or `apply` (not a strict rule). From the design point of view, if you need to have access to grandparent, something is wrong in your design (tight coupling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have classes. It only has objects. And objects inherits from their prototypes, which in turn inherits from their prototypes and so forth. If you want to learn more about making inheritance in javascript take a look at http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html. Though this is doable, if you want to mimic classes and class-inheritence in javascript I recommend using a framework designed for this such as MooTools.